# How do we solve the problem about bad behavior (unfair evaluation) in lab?

Tags: undergraduate, policy, course-evaluation

My undergraduate student told me that he had some problems when he attended the lab session in our department. This lab session is mandatory and one of the components of the course evaluation.

The source of the problem is the lab assistants. They asked him many irrelevant questions about their student union, like the name of the chair, secretary, etc. Unfortunately, he is not a member of this union, so he could not answer. Therefore, they failed him and he has to retake the test.

I want to help my student.

Previously, I considered reporting this case to the chair. However, I remembered that my chair once said that he did not like students who do not join the student union. Hence, I did not report to him.

Do you know the best way to solve this problem with minimum effort?

For further information, the university is located in a developing country in South East Asia.

Note:
The union is a student organization. Historically, the union were the response for the repressive regime. To become a member of the union, the student should attend some orientation activity. Most of the activity is hazing.

Comment: Is there a "Director of Undergraduate Studies" or similar person whose role is to oversee undergraduate teaching?

Comment: The chair is responsible for the undergraduate teaching. However, the chair dislike non-member of the student union.

Comment: _Do you know the best way to solve this problem with minimum effort?_ Sorry to sound pessimistic, but I doubt that the problem can be solved even with _maximum_ effort. You are effectively asking how to solve systemic political corruption in a country rife with it. That seems to me to be beyond the powers of this forum. The only practical suggestion I can think of is for the student to join the student union in question, but I'm guessing there are some strong reasons why he does not want to do that.

Comment: Unions, the gift that keeps on giving.  Wait, shouldn't all that information be freely available somewhere?  I mean, a student union should have to register with the school, therefore the school should have all the information on file.  If you were to be able to learn this information and disseminate the information to students in case they run into this situation in the future, problem would be solved.

Comment: @DanRomik: One of the reason why he does not want to join the union is hazing in the union's orientation.

Comment: @NZKshatriya Thanks for your suggestion. Although, I am not sure that I will get the information in detail.

Comment: @testes well good luck to you and him both. Maybe you can contact the press, or find some allies within the university who oppose this corrupt system? Anyway, sadly my skepticism remains. You are facing an uphill battle, and unless you are willing to dedicate your life to fighting this injustice, it is likely that nothing will change.

Comment: Is there anyone at a higher level than the chair who might be sympathetic?  If yes, you could go to that level, but it will probably negatively affect your relationship with the chair, which could potentially harm your career.  If not, then I think Dan Romik's comment applies.

Comment: There is the slim chance that while the individual might not like people who don't join the union they might still find it ridiculous that, say, chemistry exams or similar are including large numbers questions on irrelevant topics like details of the union. Of course that depends on how strongly the individual feels on the issue and whether they're a generally reasonable person.

Comment: @NateEldredge I will ask the advice from senior faculty, but I have to be careful to tell the right person. Most of the faculty is the alumnus of the union. I was not an undergraduate student in this university.

Comment: @Murphy There is ``nonsense solidarity" among the members of the union. My student also told me that the participant of the lab session did not want to help him.

Comment: Hang on, it's not clear that everybody is on the same page here.  Could you please edit your question and explain what you mean by "union"?  Who is part of it (just undergrads, or what?), what's it for, what do the members do, etc.?  Also, could you explain why your student couldn't just answer the questions, and then just quietly not join the union?  If this has all been written up somewhere, then just post a link.  Thanks.

Comment: A more specific title would be a good idea, too.  When you say "discrimination", most people are going to think race, gender, religion, etc.  Discrimination based on union membership is also a problem, but the solutions are likely to be quite different.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry for my bad english. I have edited my question.

Comment: @aparente001 I have edited my question. The student could not answer the question because he is not a member, so he did not the detailed information. The student should pass a selection process (include hazing),  to become a member of the union.

Comment: Thanks, the edit is helpful.  Hmm.  I'm starting to think "union" might not be an accurate description.  I'm sorry, I wish I knew more about your part of the world.  Maybe we should ask for guidance on English SE (ELU) or politics or something having to do with international stuff.

Comment: If they quizzed and graded him on campus matters as part of a science lab, I think that's ridiculous. Can they provide a list of questions that he failed to answer related to the subject he was being quizzed on? Did they give him feedback on how he could improve his performance? It's also possible that the student gave you an incomplete account of the quiz, i.e. maybe the silly questions were asked but did not count towards the grade. I'd start by investigating the bad grade, i.e. find the evidence that the lab assistants are using to justify giving the student the grade that they did.

Comment: @aparente001 While I've not heard of this particular issue before, I've certainly heard about other cases of abusively powerful student unions linked to political parties.  This is not hard to believe in certain countries.

Comment: @jakebeal - Links?  Examples?  I've only been to Europe and Latin America.  I have some gaps to fill in.

Comment: @aparente001 Communist parties frequently have student unions associated with them; when the Communist party is a powerful governing organization, it is not unusual for its student unions to be quite significant players on campus.

Comment: @jakebeal - Thank you.  But why is it called a union?  I'm getting the impression it's a misnomer.  Is there a better term?

Comment: @aparente001 I don't know about the OP's specific case, but in many cases it is very much a union in the traditional labor sense; communist parties frequently explicitly fuse labor unions and political/governmental organizations.

Comment: @jakebeal and aparente001: Recently, I got some information about the history of the student union. Initially, the membership of the student union was given to all students in a particular major (without selection). However, around late 70's & 80's, the repressive government restricted and banned many students organization in this country. The students reacted this repression by keeping their organization in secret and making new type selection of union's membership (including hazing). Some students did not want to join the union because of this selection.

Comment: ... Other students felt that these students did not have ``solidarity/friendship sense". This caused a division and hatred among students in their daily life. This tradition last from 80's until now, although the repressive government was overthrown in the late 90's.

Comment: It strongly depends on which country. As jakebeal referred to, various political organizations do various things that people outside those countries can hardly believe.  There has been a large amount of political change in the region lately, and various groups are, well, making changes. You should be exceedingly wary of this situation. You should seek advice from somebody you trust who is knowledgeable about the local situation.

Answer (score 7):

From what you have written, it appears that the fundamental problem is that you are dealing with a nakedly corrupt organization. You describe your student as having been failed for blatantly political reasons that have nothing to do with their education.

Such an action is obviously unethical, and should not be tolerated. The key questions that I see, then, are these:

1. Is there is anybody who you can work with in order to effectively oppose this corruption?
2. Does your student *want* to be a test case against corruption?

You describe your chair as being in favor of the current regime. You may wish to discuss in any case, as even if your chair doesn't like students who don't join the union, they may still be opposed to naked abuse of power by union members. If the chair will not act, are there deans or such who might? Are there other faculty members or student organizations who feel the same way as you? What about outside groups that might bring pressure, such as local or international media?

This does sound like an important fight to fight, but also remember that it is not only your fight. If their power is strong and you directly oppose them, the student union may choose to make life very difficult for your student, so before taking any direct action in opposition, it would be important to discuss potential consequences with your student. Since they did not simply take the expedient path and join the union, they may well be willing to fight; equally, however, they may have circumstances that make it problematic for them to do so, and it is not your right to make that choice on their behalf.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I try to consult to senior faculty.